# Problem curl docker container from another docker container

Tags: docker, curl, docker-compose, wget, openstack

I have the problem that when I try to reach from one Docker container to another in the same network via curl I get a gateway timeout message. Ping works. The Server is a Open Stack VM within my corporation Network.

My daemon.json looks like:

```
{
    "default-address-pools": [ { "base": "172.17.0.0/16", "size": 24 } ],
    "mtu": 1450,
    "dns": ["192.24.44.10"]
```

}

My network config in docker-compose looks like:
"networks:
my_docker_network:
name: my_docker_network
driver: bridge
driver_opts:
com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1450"

"curl -s --head  --request GET http://my_service:8080/my_service/api/version"
returns

```
HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 3531
```

Ping works fine

```
PING my_service(172.18.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from my_service.my_docker_network (172.18.0.12): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.230 ms
64 bytes from my_service.my_docker_network (172.18.0.12): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.146 ms
64 bytes from my_service.my_docker_network (172.18.0.12): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.100 ms
64 bytes from my_service.my_docker_network (172.18.0.12): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.135 ms
64 bytes from my_service.my_docker_network (172.18.0.12): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.102 ms
^C
--- my_serviceping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7153ms
```

From Host i can reach "curl -s --head  --request GET [http://127.0.0.1:8082/my_service/api/version"](http://127.0.0.1:8082/my_service/api/version%22)

wget also dont work with more expanded error:

```
Resolving proxy01.mycompany.net(proxy01.mycompany.net)...
192.100.20.20
Connecting to proxy01.mycompany.net(proxy01.mycompany.net)|192.100.20.20|:80... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 504 Gateway Timeout
Retrying.
```

Proxy is set in args from the docker-compose of every container with referencing my .env:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy01.mycompany.net:80
HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy01.mycompany.net:80
NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,10.0.0.0/8,*mycompany.net
```

URLs outside of my docker network can get reached. For example "curl -s --head  --request GET https://google.de" is working from within the container.

I am new to docker so hopefully someone can give me a hint to solve this problem.